# How can skip a query select if the value is null

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

I want to omit the last where       '   + "AND (?11!=NULL AND (s.client!=0 OR s.client!=NULL) OR s.client.contactName LIKE %?11% ) "'   if ?11 is diferent of null but is not working

My error is why  I just to add the  client atribute is a new column and   is foreign  column but I´m having errors  because i want to get my old data with null and 0 in that column

```
@Query("SELECT new com.cea.platforms.shipmentcontrol.dto.shipments.ShipmentFilterDTO("
        + "s.shipmentId,"
        + "s.shipmentStatus.catalogId,"
        + "s.shipmentStatus.catalogOptions,"
        + "s.serviceType.catalogId,"
        + "s.serviceType.catalogOptions,"
        + "s.trackingNumber,"
        + "s.trasportUnitId,"
        + "s.pkgReceptionDate,"
        + "s.deliveryDate, "
        + "s.pkgDeliveryEstimateDate, "
        + "s.register.catalogId,"
        + "s.register.catalogOptions,"
        + "s.deliveryOrderSeq) FROM ShipmentModel s " 
        + "WHERE "
        + "(?1 = NULL OR s.register.catalogId = ?1) "
        + "AND (?2 = NULL OR s.trackingNumber LIKE %?2%) "      
        + "AND (?3 = NULL OR s.serviceType.catalogId = ?3) "        
        + "AND (?4 = NULL OR s.trasportUnitId LIKE %?4%) "
        + "AND (?5 = NULL OR (CAST(s.pkgReceptionDate AS date) >= ?5)) "
        + "AND (?6 = NULL OR (CAST(s.pkgReceptionDate AS date) <= ?6)) "    
        + "AND (?7 = NULL OR (CAST(s.deliveryDate AS date) >= ?7)) "
        + "AND (?8 = NULL OR (CAST(s.deliveryDate AS date) <= ?8)) "            
        + "AND (?9 = NULL OR  s.shipmentStatus = ?9) " 
        + "AND (?10  = NULL OR s.shipmentReference IS NULL OR s.shipmentReference LIKE %?10%) "
        + "AND (?11 IS NULL OR s.client=0 OR s.client!=0 ) "
        + "AND (?11!=NULL AND (s.client!=0 OR s.client!=NULL) OR s.client.contactName LIKE %?11% ) "

        )
Page<ShipmentFilterDTO> findByFilters(Long companyId, String trackingNumber, Long serviceTypeId,
        String transportUnitId, Date receptionDate, Date receptionDateEnd, Date deliveryDate, Date deliveryDateEnd,
        Long shipmentStatusId,String reference,String ClientName, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, comparing anything to `null` produces a `null` result, regardless of the actual value being compared. Typically, `NULL = NULL` is `NULL`, and `1 <> NULL` is `NULL as well`.

You need to replace all `... = NULL` predicates in the code with `... IS NULL`. Accordingly, `... != NULL` should be `... IS NOT NULL`.

I am also suspicious about the precedence of predicates in the last condition:

```
AND (
    ?11 IS NOT NULL 
    AND (s.client <> 0 OR s.client IS NOT NULL) 
    OR s.client.contactName LIKE %?11% 
)
```

This really means:

```
AND (
    ?11 IS NOT NULL 
    AND ((s.client <> 0 OR s.client IS NOT NULL) OR s.client.contactName LIKE %?11%) 
)
```

Is this the logic you want? Else, you probably need to surround some of the predicates with parentheses. For example:

```
AND (
    (?11 IS NOT NULL AND (s.client <> 0 OR s.client IS NOT NULL))
    OR s.client.contactName LIKE %?11% 
)
```

Comment: Thank you i will try it. My error is why  I just to add the  client atribute is a new column and   is foreign  column but I´m having errors  because i want to get my old data with null and 0 in that column

Comment: I tried with the  last query but  I get  results with valid id  in   s.client.contactName i need  invalids results  in  s.client.contactName  too;